# Basic vuetify layout issues. I'm struggling to keep 3 flex elements from expanding past screen height

Tags: layout, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am having some issues using the vuetify layout grid.

I have 3 v-flex elements in a v-layout inside my component.
One is a toolbar(top), one is for content(middle) and the other an action-bar(bottom)

I need the content(middle) v-flex to not push the bottom one off screen when the content inside of it expands to whatever height, it needs to stay the size that it would if there was no content inside of it. ie 10 of 12 rows. All 3 should remain in place.

Layout from app.vue is

```
<v-content app :dir="appDirection">
  <v-container fluid fill-height>
    <v-layout column >
      <v-flex xs12>
        <router-view/>
      </v-flex>
     </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</v-content>
```

In router view I have a page with

```
<v-layout>
  <v-navigation-drawer></v-navigation-drawer>
  <my-component></my-component> 
</v-layout>
```

in my component I have:

```
<v-layout column>
  <v-flex xs1 sm1 md1 lg1> //TOOLBAR(top)
      <v-toolbar></v-toolbar>
  </v-flex>

  <v-flex xs10 sm10 md10 lg10 > //CONTENT(middle)
      <ul>
          <v-infinite-scroll> should inherit dimensions and scroll
          </v-infinite-scroll>
      </ul>
  </v-flex>
  <v-flex xs1 sm1 md1 lg1>//ACTIONBAR(bottom)
      <v-text-field></v-text-field>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

If anyone knows how to achieve this your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You need to first understand how `v-flex` inside `v-layout` works with prop `column` works.

When Column prop is set. `v-flex` takes the available height(not the screen-height/content-height) and divide it to 12 point grid system.

All you need to do is put height of the container (here `v-layout`). That will solve your problem.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the answer but alas, nope, I've added specific height to all of the parent containers and it still expands past the screen dimensions.